Film about racism, man breaks up with light skinned woman cause her mom is black
This movie is about a black single mom whose daughter is very light skinned. The daughter tries to fit into white society, dates a white boy, I think they were to be married. She didn't want him to meet her mom, and once he did he broke it off with her.
The movie may have come out in the early 1960s, perhaps black & white. I thought the young woman was played by Natalie Woods but I haven't found anything like it accredited to her.

I believe some, or at least when she was a teenager her and her mom lived on or near a beach, or perhaps were visiting

In which case, could this be Imitaton of Life?
Despite the progressive subject matter, the film was infact more about ambition and identity than any real race agenda.

In 1947, widow Lora Meredith (Lana Turner) dreams of becoming a famous Broadway actress. Losing track of her young daughter Susie at the beach (portrayed as a child by Terry Burnham), she asks a stranger named Steve Archer (John Gavin) to help her find the girl. Susie is found and looked after by Annie Johnson (Juanita Moore), a black single mother who also has a daughter, Sarah Jane (portrayed as a child by Karin Dicker), who is about Susie's age. Sarah Jane inherited her father's fair skin and can pass for white...
... trouble ensues .. etc..
... When Annie learns the truth, she goes to the club to claim her daughter; Sarah Jane is fired. Her rejection of her mother begins taking a physical and mental toll on Annie. When Lora returns from Italy, Sarah Jane has run away from home. She asks Steve to hire a detective to find her. The detective locates Sarah Jane in California, living as a white woman under an assumed name and working as a chorus girl. [...] Annie is bedridden upon her return to New York, and Lora and Susie look after her. The issue of Susie's crush on Steve becomes serious when Susie learns that Steve and Lora are to be married.


I think this is it, although after watching I didn't see the only scene I remembered well. thanks

This is John Cassavetes seminal race movie Shadows.
The film is frequently hailed a masterpiece, not only for it's progressive race agenda and stark portrayal of civil-rights era America (the film was shot in 1957, deep into the movement, but whilst considered the first indie is also one of the first 'mainstream' films to tackle the subject), but also for it's detailed and faultless depiction of the beat era, soundtrack and all.
Leila Goldoni (who was actually of Italian descent) plays Leila, who is in the early stages of a romance with Tony (Anthony Ray). In the last act of the film, Leila invites Tony to a party and is introduced to her brothers Hugh (Hugh Hurd) and Ben (Ben Carruthers), both of whom are prominently black.

thanks for the input but this isn't it. It was just a single mom and daughter, no brothers. and wasn't about musicians. the movie starts when she's young and shows her life as she grows and eventually hates her mom cause she's black.
